# File can't read XML on other Computer

Tags: xml, powershell

I coded a script to export documents in SAP and to run a macro in Excel for these. Everything worked out perfectly on my computer.
Unfortunately the requirement is to run this script on several computers. The problem is that I can't read the XML in my PowerShell on another computer.

To explain my PowerShell script, first I export the documents out of SAP, that works perfectly. When I try to read the XML file to get the specific path to the documents, I get the following error.

> Unable to find type [ xml ]: make sure that the assembly containing thistype is loaded.

Then I tried to find out which assembly I have to add to read the XML. So I first tried:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.Serialization
```

Didn't work. Then I tried to create an object with `System.XML.XmlDocument`.

```
$xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.Load("C:\Users\mtn\AppData\Roaming\KPIReport\DIS.xml")
[xml] $xdoc = Get-Content "C:\Users\mtn\AppData\Roaming\KPIReport\DIS.xml"
$xdoc.SelectNodes("//DIS_PDP")
```

There I got the following error:

> The term 'New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I checked the execution policy for the PowerShell to run the script as well, but it's still not working.

Just don't know where the problem is. For your understanding that's my PowerShell code:

```cs
$profile = $env:userprofile

$vbsPDPPath = "$env:userprofile\AppData\Roaming\KPIReport"
$vbsPDPName = "SAP-ExportPDP.vbs"

$processNamePDP = $vbsPDPPath + "\" + $vbsPDPName

Start-Process $processNamePDP -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait

$vbsFOLDERPath = "$env:userprofile\AppData\Roaming\KPIReport"
$vbsFOLDERName = "SAP-ExportFOLDER.vbs"

$processNameFOLDER = $vbsFOLDERPath + "\" + $vbsFOLDERName
Start-Process $processNameFOLDER -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait

# read the registry entry to know which file to use
$KeyPath = 'Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ Explorer\User Shell Folders'
$ValueName = 'Report'

$PathToXML = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $KeyPath -Name $ValueName).$ValueName

# parse XML
[xml] $report = Get-Content $PathToXML

# get the number of files, that have to be located in the specific folder
# to run the macro accurate
$counter = $report.Reports.Report.DIS_PDP.Count + $report.Reports.Report.DIS_FOLDER.Count

# if condition to be sure that everything is saved in the folder
if ((Get-ChildItem $profile\AppData\Roaming\KPIReport\Test | Measure-Object).Count -eq $counter) {
  # run the personal macro for every PATH_PDP in the XML
  foreach ($FilePath in $report.Reports.Report.PATH_PDP) {
    $i = "$($profile)$FilePath"
    $excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
    $excel.WindowState = 2
    $excel.Visible = $false
    $wbPersonalXLSB = $excel.Workbooks.Open($profile + $PersonalXLSB)
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($i)
    $worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    $excel.Run($RunMacro)
    $wbPersonalXLSB.Close()
    $workbook.Save()
    $workbook.Close()
    $excel.Quit()
  }

  # delete the temporary folder with the documents
  $deleteFiles = Get-Item $profile\AppData\Roaming\KPIReport\Test
  $deleteFiles | Remove-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force -Recurse
} else {
  MsgBox("foo")
}
```

The error often refers to this line:

```
[xml] $report = Get-Content $PathToXML
```

but on my computer it works without an error.

[image: $PSVersionTable: left - my computer - PSVersion 5.0, right - non functional computer - PSVersion 2.0]

Comment: Compare the PowerShell versions on both computers (`$PSVersionTable`).

Comment: check whether XML has any junk values.

Comment: I think this is provided by .Net. Can you confirm which versions of .Net are installed on the non functioning computers?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers just edited my question with the PowerShell versions of both computer. I suppose the non functioning has an older version, that can't read XML?!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the Version of .Net on the non functioning computer:       4.6.0.1.55

Comment: Upgrade PowerShell to version 3.0 or newer.

Comment: It worked out...can read the XML file now!